# Invalid Login Token error while executing jmeter recorded script

Tags: jmeter, moodle

I am new to jmeter. I have recorded script in jmeter for Moodle.

Recorded Scenario/Steps:

1. Access Moodle Application.
2. Login with authorized user.
3. Click on courses link.
4. Logout.

Test Run Details:

Running recorded script with more than 50 users having same user credentials (as application supports multi login)

Error shared by server monitoring team (during execution of jmeter script):

[image: invalid Login Token]

Answer (score 1):

In the majority of cases you cannot just replay the recorded script, modern web applications widely use dynamic parameters i.e. for [client-side state tracking](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/225740/what-is-view-state-and-how-it-works-in-Asp-Net53/) or [security reasons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)

In case of Moodle you need to pass the [Login token](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Login_token) along with the credentials, it can be extracted from the login page response using i.e. [CSS Selector Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter)

Demo:

[image]

Full test plan just in case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jmeterTestPlan version="1.2" properties="5.0" jmeter="5.2.1">
    <hashTree>
        <TestPlan guiclass="TestPlanGui" testclass="TestPlan" testname="Test Plan" enabled="true">
            <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments"></stringProp>
            <boolProp name="TestPlan.functional_mode">false</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="TestPlan.tearDown_on_shutdown">true</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="TestPlan.serialize_threadgroups">false</boolProp>
            <elementProp name="TestPlan.user_defined_variables" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
                <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
            </elementProp>
            <stringProp name="TestPlan.user_define_classpath"></stringProp>
        </TestPlan>
        <hashTree>
            <ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="Thread Group" enabled="true">
                <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
                <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
                    <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
                    <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">1</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
                <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">1</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">1</stringProp>
                <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
                <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration"></stringProp>
                <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay"></stringProp>
                <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.same_user_on_next_iteration">true</boolProp>
            </ThreadGroup>
            <hashTree>
                <CookieManager guiclass="CookiePanel" testclass="CookieManager" testname="HTTP Cookie Manager" enabled="true">
                    <collectionProp name="CookieManager.cookies"/>
                    <boolProp name="CookieManager.clearEachIteration">false</boolProp>
                    <boolProp name="CookieManager.controlledByThreadGroup">false</boolProp>
                </CookieManager>
                <hashTree/>
                <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" testname="Open Moodle Login Page" enabled="true">
                    <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="HTTPArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
                        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
                    </elementProp>
                    <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">sandbox.moodledemo.net</stringProp>
                    <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port"></stringProp>
                    <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol">https</stringProp>
                    <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.contentEncoding"></stringProp>
                    <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">/login/index.php</stringProp>
                    <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">GET</stringProp>
                    <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
                    <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
                    <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">true</boolProp>
                    <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.DO_MULTIPART_POST">false</boolProp>
                    <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.embedded_url_re"></stringProp>
                    <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.connect_timeout"></stringProp>
                    <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.response_timeout"></stringProp>
                </HTTPSamplerProxy>
                <hashTree>
                    <HtmlExtractor guiclass="HtmlExtractorGui" testclass="HtmlExtractor" testname="CSS Selector Extractor" enabled="true">
                        <stringProp name="HtmlExtractor.refname">logintoken</stringProp>
                        <stringProp name="HtmlExtractor.expr">input[name=logintoken]</stringProp>
                        <stringProp name="HtmlExtractor.attribute">value</stringProp>
                        <stringProp name="HtmlExtractor.default"></stringProp>
                        <boolProp name="HtmlExtractor.default_empty_value">false</boolProp>
                        <stringProp name="HtmlExtractor.match_number"></stringProp>
                        <stringProp name="HtmlExtractor.extractor_impl"></stringProp>
                    </HtmlExtractor>
                    <hashTree/>
                </hashTree>
                <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" testname="Perform Login" enabled="true">
                    <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="HTTPArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
                        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments">
                            <elementProp name="username" elementType="HTTPArgument">
                                <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.always_encode">false</boolProp>
                                <stringProp name="Argument.value">admin</stringProp>
                                <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
                                <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.use_equals">true</boolProp>
                                <stringProp name="Argument.name">username</stringProp>
                            </elementProp>
                            <elementProp name="password" elementType="HTTPArgument">
                                <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.always_encode">false</boolProp>
                                <stringProp name="Argument.value">sandbox</stringProp>
                                <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
                                <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.use_equals">true</boolProp>
                                <stringProp name="Argument.name">password</stringProp>
                            </elementProp>
                            <elementProp name="logintoken" elementType="HTTPArgument">
                                <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.always_encode">false</boolProp>
                                <stringProp name="Argument.value">${logintoken}</stringProp>
                                <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
                                <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.use_equals">true</boolProp>
                                <stringProp name="Argument.name">logintoken</stringProp>
                            </elementProp>
                            <elementProp name="anchor" elementType="HTTPArgument">
                                <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.always_encode">false</boolProp>
                                <stringProp name="Argument.value"></stringProp>
                                <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
                                <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.use_equals">true</boolProp>
                                <stringProp name="Argument.name">anchor</stringProp>
                            </elementProp>
                        </collectionProp>
                    </elementProp>
                    <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">sandbox.moodledemo.net</stringProp>
                    <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port"></stringProp>
                    <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol">https</stringProp>
                    <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.contentEncoding"></stringProp>
                    <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">/login/index.php</stringProp>
                    <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">POST</stringProp>
                    <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
                    <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
                    <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">true</boolProp>
                    <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.DO_MULTIPART_POST">false</boolProp>
                    <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.embedded_url_re"></stringProp>
                    <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.connect_timeout"></stringProp>
                    <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.response_timeout"></stringProp>
                </HTTPSamplerProxy>
                <hashTree/>
                <ResultCollector guiclass="ViewResultsFullVisualizer" testclass="ResultCollector" testname="View Results Tree" enabled="true">
                    <boolProp name="ResultCollector.error_logging">false</boolProp>
                    <objProp>
                        <name>saveConfig</name>
                        <value class="SampleSaveConfiguration">
                            <time>true</time>
                            <latency>true</latency>
                            <timestamp>true</timestamp>
                            <success>true</success>
                            <label>true</label>
                            <code>true</code>
                            <message>true</message>
                            <threadName>true</threadName>
                            <dataType>true</dataType>
                            <encoding>false</encoding>
                            <assertions>true</assertions>
                            <subresults>true</subresults>
                            <responseData>false</responseData>
                            <samplerData>false</samplerData>
                            <xml>false</xml>
                            <fieldNames>true</fieldNames>
                            <responseHeaders>false</responseHeaders>
                            <requestHeaders>false</requestHeaders>
                            <responseDataOnError>false</responseDataOnError>
                            <saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>true</saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>
                            <assertionsResultsToSave>0</assertionsResultsToSave>
                            <bytes>true</bytes>
                            <sentBytes>true</sentBytes>
                            <url>true</url>
                            <threadCounts>true</threadCounts>
                            <idleTime>true</idleTime>
                            <connectTime>true</connectTime>
                        </value>
                    </objProp>
                    <stringProp name="filename"></stringProp>
                </ResultCollector>
                <hashTree/>
            </hashTree>
        </hashTree>
    </hashTree>
</jmeterTestPlan>
```

Answer (score 0):

While you are executing the script, you have to co-relate either the cookie or any request header having token. Recorded script do not work as each time for login new token is generated.

Check the request header passed and cookies

Comment: Dear V.Varshney,
Thanks for your input. Infact i already added http header manager, http cookie manager and http cache manager under my Test Plan.

Comment: yes but every time they do not work automatically, sometimes you have to extract the cookies or values from response headers and then pass it in the request headers